# Can unity shell run kde or gnome apps?

Tags: unity, software-installation

I wanna install an app, but I read in the requirement section that it's only run in gnome and Kde desktop, is that mean that can't work in Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Which app do you mean?

Comment: Android studio, but I just wanna know in general case.

Comment: Ok, thx. And also in this case, my answer is the same :)

Answer (score 3):

Usually you can use all apps of any desktop environment in any other desktop environment. During installation, all required libraries are also installed. However, the applications can look a little strange if they are specifically designed for an environment.